Load modules in the environment where vscode cmake runs
I have created a CMakePresets.json file for a project where I use some libraries that use Kokkos and uses a custom compiler called nvcc_wrapper. I have added two scripts as CMAKE_COMMAND to load the modules but still cannot configure. I can configure the project in terminal with the same command as vscode auto configuration runs with cmake-tools but the cmake-tools configuration break with the following error
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "default",
            "description": "Default settings for my cmake project",
            "hidden": false,
            "binaryDir": "${workspaceFolder}/build",
            "environment": {
                "CMAKE_COMMAND": "load-tools && source load.sh"
            },
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
                "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "YES",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "/user/kokkos/bin/nvcc_wrapper"
            }
        }
    ]
}

[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
[cmake] -- The CUDA compiler identification is unknown
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /user/kokkos/bin/nvcc_wrapper
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /user/kokkos/bin/nvcc_wrapper
[cmake] CMake Error at /opt/cmake/3.20.0/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
[cmake]   The C++ compiler
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "/user/kokkos/bin/nvcc_wrapper"
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   It fails with the following output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Change Dir: .../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
[cmake]     
[cmake]     Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_ee03d/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_ee03d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_ee03d.dir/build
[cmake]     gmake[1]: Entering directory '.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
[cmake]     Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ee03d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
[cmake]     /user/kokkos/bin/nvcc_wrapper    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ee03d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c .../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
[cmake]     /user/kokkos/bin/nvcc_wrapper: line 658: nvcc: command not found
[cmake]     gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_ee03d.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_ee03d.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 127
[cmake]     gmake[1]: Leaving directory '.../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
[cmake]     gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_ee03d/fast] Error 2
[cmake]     
[cmake]     
[cmake] 
[cmake]   
[cmake] 
[cmake]   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
[cmake]   No CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER could be found.
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
[cmake]   variable "CUDACXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER to the full
[cmake]   path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 

The project configures with the same environment variables as I have added in the preset file but cmake-tools cannot configure whereas on terminal it works without any issue. I need to load some modules before running the cmake command and added them in the preset file but they aren't solving it. I also tried execute_process() but it executed those commands after finding out the compilers but my compilers come as module and they are dependent on multiple modules which makes it really complicated to set the environment variables directly.

nvcc: command not found is a clear enough error message.

I need to load some modules to avail nvcc in the environment. But I didn't find any to load them. I have collected them in load-tools script and tried to source them in the CMakePresets.json but it didn't work.
